# Angular CLI: prefix to path of images into CSS

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In component css the link to image looks like this:

```
background: url("/assets/map.jpg");
```

but I need that in production css paths to images will be resolved like this:

```
background: url("/static/assets/map.jpg");
```

Can do this by Angular CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [isDevMode](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/isDevMode-function.html) with ngClass. Let say you have css as below

```
.bg-dev {
    background: url("/assets/map.jpg");
}

.bg-prod {
    background: url("/static/assets/map.jpg");
}
```

Use ngClass to switching between this 2 class.

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'bg-dev': devMode , 'bg-prod': !devMode}">...</some-element>
```

and in your component

```
import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent { 
  devMode:boolean = false;

  constructor() {
     this.devMode = isDevMode();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if is a lot of these CSS classes in an application then the logic will be complicated. I think this case is in need post-processing CSS.

Comment: You're welcome. The other solution is use gulp task to generate multiple  assets folder for dev and prod.